# Как проиграть анимацию StoryBoard при событии Tapped?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть приложение UWP, в нем осуществляется навигация по страницам с отображением различного контента.
В отдельном xaml файле отрисовал анимацию нажатия на экран (примерно как на этой картинке, только без руки).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно проигрывать эту анимацию, при нажатии на любую область в приложении? По сути это обратная связь на прикосновение.

Есть костыль, вне области экрана помещать отрисованные мной эллипсы и в page resources помещать storyboard после чего при эвенте tapped переносить этот объект в позицию pointer и запускать анимацию. Но делать так не хочется в виду того, что не получится проигрывать несколько экземпляров этой анимации (опять же без костылей). Плюс придется городить этот костыль на каждой из страниц.

```
   <Grid x:Name="circlePointer" Canvas.Left="-770" Canvas.Top="-435" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" Height="400" Panel.ZIndex="4">
        <Ellipse x:Name="el1" Height="400" Stroke="#FF852EF9" StrokeThickness="5" Width="400" Panel.ZIndex="4" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" />
        <Ellipse x:Name="el2" Height="400" Stroke="#FF852EF9" StrokeThickness="5" Width="400" Panel.ZIndex="4" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10"/>
        <Ellipse x:Name="el3" Height="400" Stroke="#FF852EF9" StrokeThickness="5" Width="400" Panel.ZIndex="4" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10"/>
    </Grid>
```

И код стартующий анимацию

```
private void mainWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Canvas.SetTop(circlePointer, Mouse.GetPosition(this).Y - 200);
    Canvas.SetLeft(circlePointer, Mouse.GetPosition(this).X - 200);
    playStoryBoard("anim_pulse");
}
```

Comment: Зачем за пределами экрана. Пусть анимационный блок (контрол) будет полностью прозрачным в спокойном состоянии. Как только юзер тыкнул, перемещаете блок в координатам и запускаете анимацию. Мне кажется, что это реализовать можно полностью в XAML. Посмотрите например как устроен `ProgressRing`. Вам по сути то же самое надо, только со своей анимашкой и дополнительно управлять координатами.

Comment: Мне нужно запускать несколько экземпляров данной анимации. Пример: пользователь несколько раз ткнул на экран в разные места. В этих координатах надо запустить анимацию.

Comment: Значит надо создать самоуничтожающийся контрол и спавнить его по координатам. Он типа появился, отыграл анимацию, удалился. Либо создать динамический пул таких контролов для увеличения производительности. А спавнить их можно на прозрачном гриде, который занимает все окно, поверх остальных контролов. У вас с одной анимацией получилось? Покажите разметку и код.

Comment: @aepot добавил код в вопрос. "anim_pulse" - обычный StoryBoard. Сейчас этот грид вместо со своим сторибордом на каждой странице, причем если нажимать на экран до того как закончится анимация, предыдущая останавливается (что логично). Скажите пожалуйста, как создавать самоуничтожающийся контрол с анимацией?

Comment: Анимацию тоже покажите пожалуйста и метод, который ее запускает. Сделайте так, чтобы можно было воспроизвести то, что вы сделали, а не выдумывать решение с нуля.

Comment: @aepot https://pastebin.com/sqrBpP34
там xaml и cs к нему.

Сейчас переписываю проект с wpf на uwp, поэтому не удивляйтесь